Javacript code not working without console of developer tools of browser
I am working on a .Net razor pages web app. The web app has an authentication system in it when the authentication system validates the user the user goes to the index page of the user end of the website but the user can navigate back to the previous(login) page. I wanted that when the user wants to go back to the previous page the system automatically triggers a button which is coded in _layout.cshtml file. I have coded a javascript code but that code only works if the console of developer tools of the browser is open can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my javascript code??
Following is the javascript code:
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        var logoutButton = document.getElementById('logoutButton');

        window.onpopstate = function () {
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
            logoutButton.click();
        };
    </script>
}

Please fix the error of the code I have explained

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a different way to approach it than what you have written.

What is the approach can you please tell me...

@ryanwebjackson I just basically wanted that if the user is logged in and presses the back button the system triggers the _layout.cshtml button instead of going back to login page

And what is the logic behind that button? Could you call it inside of the above event handler instead forcing the button click? Or could you let the navigation happen, and then run the same logic based on setting a session variable in the browser?

@ryanwebjackson No I do not want to let the navigation happen to the previous page, my first requirement is that my page must not navigate to the previous page at any condition and the button is navigating to an asp-page and some javascript code is applied on the button in _layout.cshtml file

Can this be achievable through javascript or should I change the approach and go for controller to achieve my task?
